# GPS navigation software/SDK for Linux

Tags: linux, navigation, gps, embedded-linux

Is there a (open source or commercial) software solution available for the **Linux** platform to build a custom embedded navigation device? It should be able to display maps and do routing (just like a TomTom/Navigon/Garmin/... navi device).

Unfortunately all navigation solutions seem to target Windows CE only.

Something based on OpenStreeMap data is *not* an option, because the map data is IMHO not always good enough for serious routing / driving instructions.

Since I'm searching for a long time now without luck I'm not too restrictive on the implementation details, however it should be possible to extend the software with custom functions or ideally embed the navigation in my own software.

*Android* with Google Maps comes to my mind, but I'd like to avoid setting up Android for my device.

Alternatively, **if there is no such solution, I might use a end-user navigation device** if that allows me some kind of communication with my own device to control it.

I'm open for any suggestions, thanks..

Comment: Do you know anyone (commercial) which comes with an SDK and is stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a huge list **[here](http://tuxmobil.org/linux_gps_navigation_applications.html)**. Take a look if anything suites your needs.